# C# and Webview Control, how to know when javascript is completed?

Tags: javascript, c#, webview

When using the WebView control with c# (csharp). How can I know when the page has finished loaded and finished the javascript that is on the page. So far I can get that the page is loaded. However, when I check for certain things on the page, they are not there. So I get an error generate because the javascript on the page hasn't completed.

Any ideas on how to get this with WebView control. Not the webbrowser control.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `WebView.NavigationCompleted` event is the thing you're looking for. You can use this event to do something when the page completely loads. Here's an example:

```
webView.NavigationCompleted += (webSender, webE) => {
    // things to do when page is loaded
}
```